# How to do better quality of texture on DEM in qgis2threejs?

Tags: qgis, raster, resolution, qgis2threejs, texture

I use as texture for DEM image with original resolution 4000x4000px. But when qgis2threejs creating 3D model in browser - texture looks like image with low quality.
In plugin menu there is line "resolution"

[image]
when i choose 200% or 400% quality are not changing.
How to do better quality of texture?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating a large image and using it as a texture, you can divide whole model into blocks and assign images to each block. Try the "Surroundings" option.

Comment: if i try the "Surroundings" option  the option "Clip DEM by polygon "is not active. It is important to me - it well limits the size of my model. And I did not notice that the quality of the textures is changing

Answer (score 1):

Under resampling not display. Check plugin documentation: https://qgis2threejs.readthedocs.io/en/docs-release/ExportSettings.html

Comment: in documentation is written that: "If map canvas image is selected as the display type, texture image size for each block is maximum 256 x 256". It turns out that to get a texture of 512x512 need to divide the DEM into 4 parts?